# Can someone please tell me the name of this flower?

Tags: identification, flowers

[image]

Can someone please tell me the name of this flower? I know that it's a little hard to see the flower in this photo my apologies :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the flowers in the picture appear to be varieties of Rose - if you specifically mean the white tinged pink one in the centre, I don't know which variety it is, there are zillions of different roses available, and this isn't one I recognise. The closest I can find that's similar is Rosa Penelope, image can be seen [here](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Rose_Penelope_20070601.jpg).

For a more accurate ID, things like foliage, thorns (or not), scent, hips, height and spread and growth habit are necessary to know.

Comment: Perfect answer, this should be acknowledged or at least have a reply from OP.

Comment: @stormy oooh, no, no, no, I hate 'shoulds and oughts'... I feel differently about these things, it goes like this:: question - answer (good bad or indifferent answer) - response or otherwise is now down to the asker, I've discharged my chosen duty, job done, end of story, no acknowledgement necessary, the box is ticked so to speak and I move on. Can be nice if you get a response, but not necessary, itsabout clear accurate information, or facilitating accurate information dispersal, that's why I do it, subsequent votes and thanks are inesssential. I'm not always entirely accurate, but I try...